# Discord.js bot can't kick members

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Here is the code:

```
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
        const [CMD_NAME, ...args] = message.content
          .trim()
          .substring(PREFIX.length)
          .split(/\s+/);
        
        if (CMD_NAME === 'kick') {
            if (args.length === 0) return message.reply('Provide an ID');
            const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
            if (member) {
                member.kick();
            } else {
                message.channel.send('User not found');
            }

        } 
    }
});
```

For some reason, the bot always outputs "User not found" even when I use the id of the user.
the bot has permission to do so, Does anybody know the solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of recent changes in the [`Discord Api`](https://discord.com/developers/docs) that the `Guild` cache is empty , to fix this you have these options -

- 1. Enable the `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT`  Intent in Discord Developer Portal
- 2. Fetch the guild member `message.guild.members.fetch(args[0])`